# Accessing Two Objects shares the same PersistentSet cause no session or session was closed?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

Just started a project that has a strange database design from the previous developers.  And I found a workaround fix for the problem already.  But I want to hear from others on why it is happening since **OpenSessionInViewFilter** is configured in web.xml and work properly on lazy loaded sets except this case.  Below is a modified version of the real code to explain the scenario.

The only thing I can think of is the the both proteins in the example has the same reference to the same set that is linked with the ncbiGI number of 66275854.  Has anyone encounter similar issue and know why?

Protein.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Protein")
public class Protein implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8578992962633035166L;
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Protein.class);
    Long id;
    String ncbiName;
    String ncbiGI;
    Set<WhOrtholog> whOrthologs;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ProteinId")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NCBIProteinGI")
        public String getNcbiGi() {
        return ncbiGI;
    }

    public void setNcbiGI(String ncbiGI) {
        this.ncbiGI = ncbiGI;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = WhOrtholog.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NCBIPROTEINGI", referencedColumnName = "NCBIPROTEINGI", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public Set<WhOrtholog> getWhOrthologs() {
        return whOrthologs;
    }

    public void setWhOrthologs(Set<WhOrtholog> whOrthologs) {
        this.whOrthologs = whOrthologs;
    }
}
```

WhOrtholog.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WH_ORTHOLOG")
public class WhOrtholog implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8633704022470442701L;
    private Long id;
    private Long score;
    private String source;
    private String strainName;
    private String ncbiProteinGi;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Ortholog_Id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "SCORE")
    public Long getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    public void setScore(Long score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Column(name = "SOURCE")
    public String getSource() {
        return this.source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Column(name = "STRAINNAME")
    public String getStrainName() {
        return this.strainName;
    }

    public void setStrainName(String strainName) {
        this.strainName = strainName;
    }

    @Column(name = "NCBIPROTEINGI")
    public String getNcbiProteinGi() {
        return ncbiProteinGi;
    }

    public void setNcbiProteinGi(String ncbiProteinGi) {
        this.ncbiProteinGi = ncbiProteinGi;
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.html")
public class TestController {
    @Resource
    private LookupService lookupService;
    @RequestMapping(params = "method=test")
    public void testSameWhOrthologSet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        Protein mainProtein = lookupService.findProteinById(3635595L);

        Protein secondProtein = lookupService.findProteinById(2486174L);
        // exception on calling mainProtein.getWhOrthologs()
        for (WhOrtholog whOrtholog : mainProtein.getWhOrthologs()) {
            // do my normal process
        }
    }

    public LookupService getLookupService() {
        return lookupService;
    }

    public void setLookupService(LookupService lookupService) {
        this.lookupService = lookupService;
    }

}
```

LookupService.java

```
public Protein findProteinById(Long proteinId) {
    return lookupDao.getProteinById(proteinId);
}
```

LookupDao.java

```
public Protein getProteinById(Long proteinId) {
    Protein protein = (Protein) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(Protein.class, proteinId);
    return protein;
}
```

Exception Stack trace

```
[15:22:19][DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter] Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
[15:22:19][DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter] Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
[15:22:19][DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter] Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
[15:22:19][DEBUG] [org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager] releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
[15:22:19][DEBUG] [org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager] transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
Feb 04, 2016 3:22:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springDispatcher] in context with path [/brc] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.test.model.Protein.whOrthologs, no session or session was closed] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.test.model.Protein.whOrthologs, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:186)
    at org.test.web.TestController.testSameWhOrthologSet(ViprGeneDetailController.java:742)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applicatio
nFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

this lazy fecth exception. you must initalize whOrthologs before returning object

```
    public Protein getProteinById(Long proteinId) {
    Protein protein = (Protein) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(Protein.class, proteinId);
    protein.getWhOrthologs();
    return protein;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kakashi!  We are using OpenSessionInViewFilter which allows us to retrieve lazy loaded PersistentSet in the later stage.

Comment: your filter include all endpoind. for example <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  this mach all endpoints

Comment: Correct, we have tested it is working properly except when loading the two different Protein records that shares the same Set of WhOrthologs in the same transaction.  If I move the for loop in the example above before secondProtein is loaded, it works fine.  But what I can not understand is why the order of the for loop matters.

Comment: I think use equals and hashcode in mapping class because your objects not  detect differences